# Пунктуация. Как оформить предложение

Tags: пунктуация

В предложениях «Если спросите, почему бы не уехать за город?» или «Если спросите, почему возник проект?» какие знаки препинания ставить? Я совсем не уверена, что поставила правильные знаки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не соглашусь, что это некорректное предложение. Всё относительно. Оно вполне может быть достаточным в рамках диалога:

> — При каких условиях вы мне расскажете историю своего проекта?
>
> — Если спросите, почему возник проект.

По содержанию — чушь, но грамматически всё в норме. Тем более, думаю, автор вопроса, Вы неспроста приводите несколько предложений. Вопрос, позволю себе догадку, не про конкретные предложения, а про принцип.
Отвечаю: наиболее простым и бесспорным знаком препинания в этом предложении будет запятая, отделяющая придаточную часть. В этом случае в конце ставится точка. В то же время можно оформить прямой речью. Тогда предложение примет следующий вид:

> Если спросите: «Почему возник проект?».

Интонационно это уже совсем другая фраза.

И немного об интонациях. Гибкость русского языка допускает в подобных случаях использовать тире: «Если спросите — почему возник проект». Конкретно в приведённых Вами примерах это будет худшее решение, но встречаются фразы, где такой вариант уместен.

Так что же ставить? Выбор за автором, но лучше всего не усложнять и обойтись простой запятой.

Answer (score 2):

*Если спросите, почему бы не уехать за город?*» некорректное предложение, неоконченное, просится продолжение: то я отвечу... Иначе в предложении два придаточных предложения, но ни одного главного.

Предложение повествовательное, в конце должна быть точка, не вопросительный знак.

То же самое и во втором: *«Если спросите, почему возник проект, мы ответим, что...*»

Comment: А если оставить его «некорректным», то вопросительный знак тоже не нужен?

Comment: _Белка: А если оставить его «некорректным», то вопросительный знак тоже не нужен?_  === Наиболее корректной будет постановка в конце разбираемых предложений многоточия... А вопросительный знак можно будет поставить, если убрать начальное "если": _Спро́сите, почему бы не уехать за город? Спро́сите, почему возник проект?_

Answer (score 0):

Знак вопроса ставится при наличии вопросительной интонации (автор на самом деле кого-то спрашивает). В обоих предложениях содержится косвенный вопрос. Вопросительной интонации нет, и в ней нет смысла, так как автор никого не спрашивает, он лишь допускает, что собеседник может это спросить. В конце ставится точка.

Розенталь:
Если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения содержит косвенный вопрос, то в конце предложения вопросительный знак обычно не ставится:
*Я прервал речь Савельича вопросом, сколько у меня всего денег.

Корчагин неоднократно спрашивал меня, когда он может выписаться.*

Однако, если косвенный вопрос содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию, в конце сложноподчиненного предложения ставится вопросительный знак:
*Скажите, пожалуйста, что это за огни?

Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником?*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88